# Django model generates hundreds of files in a saving loop

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, reportlab, temporary-files

I'm using Django 3.8.2 on Ubuntu 18.04, I'm generating a PDF file upon saving a django model but files are generated in a loop endlessly.

I have this django model:

```
class Fattura(models.Model):
   ordine = models.ForeignKey(Ordine, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="fatture", null=False)
   pdf = models.FileField(upload_to='archivio/fatture/%Y/%m')
```

the `pdf` field is generated when an instance is saved, based on the information contained in the related "ordine" field which is a ForeignKey to this other model:

```
class Ordine(models.Model):

   utente = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="ordini", null=False)
   data = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
   abbonamento = models.ForeignKey(Abbonamento, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False)
   importo = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 5, decimal_places = 2, null=False)
```

I declared every instructions for the generation of the PDF inside the `save()` method of my Fattura model. I'm using the library that is recommended by Django's documentation: reportlab. Here is the custom save method:

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

       self.count_save += 1 # I defined this attribute which I increment to understand what is actually looping
       print("COUNT SAVE: " + str(self.count_save)) # it always grows, that's the save method being re-called

       if self.pdf._file == None:

          try:
             buffer = io.BytesIO()

             p = canvas.Canvas(buffer)

             p.drawString(100,100, str(self.ordine))
             p.showPage()
             p.save()

             buffer.seek(0)

             utente = self.ordine.utente

             num_questa_fattura = utente.ordini.count()

             nome_file = "{}_{}-{}.pdf".format(
                self.ordine.utente.first_name.lower(),
                self.ordine.utente.last_name.lower(),
                num_questa_fattura)
            
             percorso = '{}/upload/archivio/fatture/{}/{}/{}'.format(
                BASE_DIR, # from settings.py
                self.ordine.data.year,
                self.ordine.data.month,
                nome_file)

             file_temporaneo = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=True)


             file_temporaneo.write(buffer.getbuffer())

             file_temporaneo.flush()

             temp_file = File(file_temporaneo, name = nome_file)

             print(nome_file)
             print(file_temporaneo)
             print("--------------------- SAVE")

             self.pdf.save(nome_file, file_temporaneo, save=True) # saving the field (EDIT: this was the problem, setting save to True resaves the whole model object, and it was creating an infinite loop)
             file_temporaneo.close()


           except:

             raise ValidationError("Invoice could not be saved")

       super().save(*args, **kwargs) # saving the object to the database
```

When I save a Fattura object with my Django admin panel hundreds of PDF files are generated inside the folder I declared, in a loop, and no database saving really completes. No Django model object is available afterward so nothing is finally saved to the database and precisely 499 files are generated each time.

I'm not sure what is causing this loop, maybe the pdf field save method in the `try` statement? Or the final `super().save(*args, **kwargs)`? I can't remove it though, otherwise nothing would be saved if a PDF file is actually associated with one instance and I'm updating the other field `ordine`

Here's an excerpt from my logs

```
[Tue Nov 02 15:25:06.974768 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 10050] [remote 95.x.x.x:36048] COUNT SAVE: 262
[Tue Nov 02 15:25:07.010584 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 10050] [remote 95.x.x.x:36048] maria_rosselli-1.pdf
[Tue Nov 02 15:25:07.015778 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 10050] [remote 95.x.x.x:36048] <tempfile._TemporaryFileWrapper object at 0x7f7b07ac0390>
[Tue Nov 02 15:25:07.020944 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 10050] [remote 95.x.x.x:36048] --------------------- SAVE
[Tue Nov 02 15:25:07.124451 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 10050] [remote 95.x.x.x:36048] COUNT SAVE: 263
[Tue Nov 02 15:25:07.164934 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 10050] [remote 95.x.x.x:36048] maria_rosselli-1.pdf
[Tue Nov 02 15:25:07.170144 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 10050] [remote 95.x.x.x:36048] <tempfile._TemporaryFileWrapper object at 0x7f7b07ac0e48>
[Tue Nov 02 15:25:07.175250 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 10050] [remote 95.x.x.x:36048] --------------------- SAVE
[Tue Nov 02 15:25:07.253426 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 10050] [remote 95.x.x.x:36048] COUNT SAVE: 264
[Tue Nov 02 15:25:07.286589 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 10050] [remote 95.x.x.x:36048] maria_rosselli-1.pdf
[Tue Nov 02 15:25:07.291734 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 10050] [remote 95.x.x.x:36048] <tempfile._TemporaryFileWrapper object at 0x7f7b07ac0e10>
[Tue Nov 02 15:25:07.296894 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 10050] [remote 95.x.x.x:36048] --------------------- SAVE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set save to False to call the model instance's save methid again when saving the pdf:

```
self.pdf.save(nome_file, file_temporaneo, save=False)
```

Comment: That was exactly the problem, it is still hard for me to understand why it was looping but it's working now. Thank you

Comment: the intended behavior of the pdf.save method is "save also the related model instance if the filefield has been modified if the parameter save=True" ... so your Fatturas save method will be called when you save the filefield which save the filefield again  and so on ... see the django docs on Filefield and Fieldfile

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#filefield-and-fieldfile